# Couldnt load module: undefinded symbol: dissector_add

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

i try to make a plugin based ASN1 dissector. I used the toyasn1 sample and only added my .asn files to the makefile of the Plugin. Now if i start wireshark i always get the error:

`Couldn't load module /wireshark-1.10-9/plugins/toyasn1/.libs/toyasn1.so: /wireshark-1.10.9/plugins/toyasn1/.libs/toysn1.so: undefined symbol: dissector_add`

The same error occours with `dissector_delete`.

Does someone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the calls to `dissector_add()` to call `dissector_add_uint()`, and the calls to `dissector_delete()` to `dissector_delete_uint()`, instead; as noted in the other answer, the names of the routines changed.

Answer (score 0):

The api changed to `dissector_add_uint()`